# C# Entity Framework : optional one to one relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a file table which either contains a url to a file somewhere on the internet OR it needs to be a physical file stored into a `varbinary(max)` column. I created a second table to store the actual `varbinary(max)` in, but I have never mapped a one to one and it is throwing an error on me that the `FileContentId` is invalid when I attempt to save.

These are my models and maps:

```
public class FileModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FileContentId { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FileTable> FileTables { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual FileContent FileContent { get; set; }
}

public class FileContent
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Contents { get; set; }

    public virtual FileModel FileModel { get; set; }   
}

public class FileMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FileModel>
{
    public FileMap()
    {
        ToTable("Files");
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        Property(t => t.Id);
        Property(t => t.Name);
        Property(t => t.FileContentId);
        Property(t => t.Url);
        Property(t => t.CreatedById);
        Property(t => t.CreatedOn);

        // Relationships
        HasRequired(t => t.CreatedBy)
            .WithMany(t => t.Files)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.CreatedById);
        HasOptional(t => t.FileContent)
            .WithRequired(t => t.FileModel)
            .Map(t => t.MapKey("FileContentId"));
    }
}
```

The error thrown is

> Invalid column name 'FileContentId'

I am certain it is the `.Map` because I added an s to the end of the value and it changed that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I was about to post the same thing:). in one to one relationShip you don't need to specify the ForeignKey, because the key in one your table will be used between two table. so if you change your code to this you will get the same result

```
 public class FileMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FileContent>
 {
    public FileMap()
   {
    ToTable("FileContent");
    HasKey(t => t.Id);




    WithRequired(t => t.FileModel)
        .HasOptional(t => t.FileContent)


   }
}
```

or you can to it with DataAnnotations(here you should specify the forgienKey.

```
  public class FileModel
{
 [Key, ForeignKey("FileContent")]
public string Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string FileContentId { get; set; }

public string Url { get; set; }
public string CreatedById { get; set; }
public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<FileTable> FileTables { get; set; }
public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
public virtual FileContent FileContent { get; set; }
 }

  public class FileContent
 {
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public byte[] Contents { get; set; }
   public virtual FileModel FileModel { get; set; }   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error I solved this, though I cannot explain how EF is populating the FileContent of the FileModel when I pull.  If anyone can explain that I will mark it as the accepted answer.

The solution was merely to remove the .Map from the relationship.

```
        public FileMap()
    {
        ToTable("Files");
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        Property(t => t.Id);
        Property(t => t.Name);
        Property(t => t.FileContentId);
        Property(t => t.Url);
        Property(t => t.CreatedById);
        Property(t => t.CreatedOn);


        // Relationships
        HasRequired(t => t.CreatedBy)
            .WithMany(t => t.Files)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.CreatedById);
        HasOptional(t => t.FileContent)
            .WithRequired(t => t.FileModel);


    }
```